# JavaScript events on related elements

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

I am wondering is the following behavior correct.

I have a label element linked to an input element via the "for" attribute, should this yield two click events on a single user click on the label? Specifically, put a click listener on window. Then, define checkbox with a label element linked to it using attribute "for". Click on the label text. The result is that checkbox will be checked and you will see two click events. http://jsfiddle.net/k55uD/2/

If this behavior is correct, are there more such cases, attributes, or whatever? Some spec would be nice.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I update the post with the example.

Comment: Can you post the code associated with your question?

Comment: No problem, my first comment appears to have been confusing, so it's removed.

Comment: Ok, I added the code and the example. Sorry for introducing confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking the `label` will trigger any `onclick` function attached to that `label` *and* any `onclick` attached to the `input` itself. Clicking the `input` will trigger *only* the `onclick` for the `input`.

This is very easy to test. See here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/zptw3/

Comment: Sorry for the last comment, I was trying to answer a different person:) Yes, I see this is happening and I can easily overcome this in the system I am trying to build by handling these corner cases. What I am wondering is there some specification for this? I am interested in behavior pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The DOM would treat each element separately, so both the label and the element it is 'for' can have event handlers defined. So yes, if both elements have an onclick handler and the click is within each element, both events will fire.

However this is something you have to define, you don't get a second click by default on the label just because it is 'for' the other element.

Basically, it is up to you - you can set it up to raise two events or a single event but out of the box you will get one event raised for the element you defined the handler on.

This explains events and event order pretty well, as well as offering some advise about browser quirks.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

EDIT:

If you Specifically, put a click listener on window. Then you will get both events due to propagation, again this is explained in the link provided.

Comment: I don't see it that way. You can make a checkbox with the label using for. Add click listener to window. Click on the label text and you will see that checkbox will be checked and you will see two events.

Comment: Your adding an event to the window, not the label or the checkbox - so yes of course that works...via propagation as indicated in the answer. If yo specifically, put a click listener on window (as per your edit) then that is the behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I've read this link before and now and it is still not giving me the answer. First, handlers are defined for capturing phase, not doing both the capturing and bubbling. Second, as the article says: "It is very important to understand that during the capturing and bubbling phases (if any) this target does not change" and in the code I provided targets are different. Third, target elements are siblings, not nested. Maybe I am missing the point? Thanks!

Comment: I just looked at your jsfiddle again, simply replace onlick with onfoucs. i.e. document.getElementById("test_label").onfoucs = function() {
    alert("test_label");
};

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are trying to say with this example. Click still remains an issue for me. As I mentioned in my post, I am interested is there a pattern when this behavior occurs. I don't think it is a bug, since it is cross-browser.